# force a change event on an DOM element without actually changing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, marionette

**Summary:**  I am trying to force a change event to fire on an HTML element, without actually changing it, but the event does not seem to fire.

**My scenario:**  There is a page (created by someone else) that is designed to hide certain fields until a value from a certain dropdown is selected, at which time the dependent fields will appear.  But in some scenarios, the dropdown should be autopopulated and fields should appear by default.  So I am trying to trick the page into showing the dependent fields when it is first loaded.  I do something like this:

```
form.field('THEDROPDOWNFIELD').$el.trigger('change');
```

But nothing happens.  I found that

```
form.field(‘THEDROPDOWNFIELD’).setValue(form.field('THEDROPDOWNFIELD').$el[0][1].value); //dummy value, first value in the list
form.field('THEDROPDOWNFIELD').$el.trigger('change');
```

will fire the change event.  For whatever reason, $el.trigger('change') does not trigger the change unless the DOM element's value truly has changed.  The problem is I don't want the dummy value in that dropdown to be there.

**Summary (again):**  Is there a way to force the dropdown's element change event to fire when the selected value in the dropdown has not actually changed?

Comment: You tagged this question with the `jquery` tag; that doesn't look like jQuery code. What is `$el`? Where does it come from? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I think the $el is from Backbone Marionette.  It is a way to get properties of the element.

Comment: OK, well the answer is "yes", at least via jQuery, but I can't tell you how to do that without seeing the markup (and I of course don't know if your event handler is a jQuery thing either). Another trick (again, with jQuery) is to establish handlers for native events such that "companion" custom events can also be used. That avoids some issues like with "click" events on things like checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works ok (uses JQuery):

```js
$('#toChange').bind('change', function() {
 $('#result').text('select changed');
})


$('#triggerChange').bind('click', function() {
 $('#toChange').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="toChange">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>First</option>
        <option>Second</option>
        <option>Third</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>
<button id="triggerChange">Click to trigger change</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to be failing, so it must be something related to the DOM or the way the other guy has implemented this effect. It is hard to guess what your problem might be. So my suggestion is as follows:

1. Check if its really implemented to trigger on radiobutton change and not on a click event handler on a div/other element that's not directly related to the radio button.
2. Check if your HTML code is failing.
3. Provide more code snippets that you think might be related.